# What was the first "revenge" movie?

Tags: first-appearance

*Payback*. *John Wick*. *High Plains Drifter*.  These are a few movies which we could consider to be "revenge" movies, where the driving action behind the protagonist is to get revenge on the parties that wronged them.  **What is the first movie, *written as a movie*, that could be considered a "revenge" movie?**  I emphasize *written as a movie* due to that the first "revenge" movie could very well be [*The Count of Monte Cristo*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0000668/) from 1908, but that was based on the book.

Answer (score 1):

[Red Heroine](https://www.cinema.ucla.edu/events/2013-10-12/red-heroine-china-1929) from 1929 would be an early example from Chinese cinema.

The film was based on popular [Wuxia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wuxia) tropes, but as far as I know, not any specific, prior work.